# Powershell: replace special characters of file names

Tags: powershell, special-characters, batch-rename

I should start off by saying that I am still a beginner in powershell scripting.

I am trying to rename all files recursively in a directory by replacing a "+" with a " " in the file name.

The command I use is: `Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "+", " "}` but doesn't work and gives me the following error:
[image]

Instead if I do this: `Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "a", " "}` everything works well.

I think the problem is with the "+" character but can't find anything on the web that tackles this problem. Does anyone know how to represent it or how to solve this?

Comment: PLEASE, don't post images of code/errors/sample-data. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must escape the plus sign and the command should work:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "\+", " "}
```